# How to filter application log lines in request_log for Google App Engine app

Tags: google-app-engine, stackdriver

In Google App Engine logs console (https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/) we can filter request_log entries and it's working fine.

But how can we filter application log lines associated with request log entry? I tried it with no success.

For example: if I set log level filter to INFO, I still see application log lines with level DEBUG.

Thanks for help in advance

**Update:**
To clarify - by "application logs" I mean logs described in this documentation section: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/logs/#request_logs_vs_application_logs